# How to combine ngrx entities using effects (which are returned periodically as a result of call from the frontend)?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

[angular] [javascript] [ngrx/entities] [ngrx/effects] [rxjs]

Following is my effects. 
This is used to fetch data from the backend.

```
//effects.ts

  loadCourierItems$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItems),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.defaultService.getCourierItems(
        ).pipe(
          map(CourierItems => CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess({ CourierItems })),
          catchError(error =>
            of(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsFailure({ error }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Following is my selector

```
//selector.ts

  export const selectCourierItemState = createFeatureSelector<CourierItemState>(
  CourierItemsFeatureKey
);

export const selectCourierItems = createSelector(selectCourierItemState, selectAll);
```

This is the component where I dispatch action to get data for the first time:

```
//app.component.ts

  constructor(private store: Store<CourierItemsState>) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadCourierItems())
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.courierItems$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCourierItems))
}
```

```
//template.html


<div *ngFor="let item of courierItems$ | async as courier>
<p>{{courier.name}}</p>
<p>{{courier.loc_cur}}</p>

etc...
</div>

...
```

How can I do this?

What I want to achieve is that I want to make a new request every 1s with the effect (backend will send back an array of 10 items) I want to combine that items in to a single entity collection.

**Updated**

```
loadCourierItems$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItems),
  exhaustMap(action => interval(1000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(CourierItemActions.stopCourierItems))),
    exhaustMap(() =>
      this.defaultService.getCourierItems(
        action.limit,
        action.start,
        action.end,
      ).pipe(
        map(courierItems => CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess({ courierItems })),
        catchError(error =>
          of(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsFailure({ error }))
        )
      )
    )
  ))
)
)
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
If I  use something like this I am being able to fetch every second and the entity collection is growing. But through this approach I am not being able to control start / stop.

```
    let date = 1587513626000; // date is required because the backend only sends data with a start and end date
    interval(1000).pipe(tap(_ => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadStoreItems({ limit: 10, start: date, end: date + 1000 }))
      date += 1000
    }))
      .subscribe()
```

**REDUCER UPDATE**

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess,
      (state, action) => adapter.addMany(action.courierItems, state)
    ),
    on(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsFailure,
      (state, action) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          error: action.error
        }
      }
    ),
```

I've tried addMany & addAll... Both are not working. Only the items from the first call are getting in to the entity collection. But in the background the request is still continuing every 1s.

**UPDATE**
This is the selector.

```
export const selectCourierItemState = createFeatureSelector<CourierItemState>(
    CourierItemsFeatureKey
  );

  export const selectCourierItems = createSelector(selectCourierItemState, selectAll);
```

Comment: Someone please help!

Comment: You need to use 
upsertMany: Add or Update multiple entities in the collection. Supports partial updates.

<pre>
  on(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess,
      (state, action) => adapter.upsertMany(action.courierItems, state)
    ),
</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your effect to send a request every second - you need the `interval` operator.

```js
//effects.ts

loadCourierItems$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItems),
    exhaustMap(action => interval(1000).pipe(
      startWith(0),
      exhaustMap(step =>
        this.defaultService.getCourierItems(
          action.limit,
          action.start + step * 1000,
          action.end + step * 1000,
        ).pipe(
          map(courierItems => CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess({ courierItems })),
          catchError(error =>
            of(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsFailure({ error }))
          )
        )
      ),
    ),
    takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(CourierItemActions.pauseStreamingCourierItems))),
    repeat(),
  )
)
```

```js
//app.component.ts

  constructor(private store: Store<CourierItemsState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(loadCourierItems());
    this.courierItems$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCourierItems));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.store.dispatch(stopCourierItems());
  }
```

Comment: What about CourierItemActions.stopCourierItems action and reducer? Do I need to write a reducer for CourierItemActions.stopCourierItems action? & does the action CourierItemActions.stopCourierItems contains any payload (props).?

Comment: What if I wanna pass extra arguments to my getCourierItem service method? It spits out that property xxxx doesnot exists of type number? When I remove the  { exhaustMap(() => interval(1000)) }, it works but the periodic requests are not working.So I tried the interval(1000) inside the component to send getRequest every 1s it works. I am being able to stop the emission, but not being able to restart evenif repeat() is pressent.

Comment: for the stop action you don't need to write a reducer, actually you can if you want to clear the list of items.

Comment: can you please answer this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427341/how-can-i-toggle-start-stop-an-ngrx-action

Comment: if you want to pass params - you need to add pipe to the interval, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to pass params. That's the only way to get data from the backend.

Comment: Done, the answer includes a way how to access the action.

Comment: still not being able to add params - errors out saying that : Property 'limit' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: could you update the question with the code you have?

Comment: Yes.. please wait.. I'll do it quickly.

Comment: It is returning first 10 items(which is the limit set). But It is also not pausing or restart streaming when I press start/stop...

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check if it works. Otherwise we can have a chat to discuss it deeper.

Comment: I can see that it is dispatching action every second, (in the network tab & redux devtools) but the returned items are not getting combined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212488/discussion-between-satantime-and-mex).

Comment: looks like this question goes to reducer now.

Comment: aha, the reducer is fine I would say. could you verify that the `CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess ` reaches the reducer every second?

Comment: Yes., I can see the action dispatching in the redux dev tools.

Comment: then let's go to the chat - the link above. I think the problem is in a reducer / selector. The effect is fine.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've a new doubt. On Slack.

Comment: Hi Mike One more help please. On  Slack.

Comment: Hi Mike Can you please check slack?

Comment: Hi Mike need help :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841325/how-to-fix-ngrx-store-throwing-error-while-testing

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use
**upsertMany:** Add or Update multiple entities in the collection. Supports partial updates.

```
  on(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess,
      (state, action) => adapter.upsertMany(action.courierItems, state)
    ),
```