# How can I toggle (start/ stop) an ngrx action?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Below is an action that dispatches a load action to the store. The corresponding effect will handle the request and sends back the response items.

But What I want is I want to toggle the below action with a button.

So if I press start it will start dispatching actions every 1 s and if I press pause, it will pause dispatching and again If I press start it will continue from where it left, and repeats so...

How can I toggle such an action?

```
    let date = 1587513626000; // date is required because the backend only sends data with a start and end date
    interval(1000).pipe(tap(_ => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadStoreItems({ limit: 10, start: date, end: date + 1000 }))
      date += 1000
    }))
      .subscribe()
```

I've tried a bunch of operators, some of them are partially working (like sometimes using takeWhile/ takeUntil I'm being able to pause) but not being able to restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have a toggle in an effect you need 2 actions (start and stop) and to use `takeUntil`.

```js
//effects.ts

  loadCourierItems$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(actions.start),
      exhaustMap(action => interval(1000).pipe(
        // logic for every second activity.
        map(actions.everySecondAction()),
      )),
      takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(actions.stop))),
      repeat(),
    )
  )
```

```js
//app.component.ts

  constructor(private store: Store<CourierItemsState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(startAction());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.store.dispatch(stopAction());
  }
```